# Ubuntu 20.04 got stucked while booting

Tags: boot, 20.04, disk

My laptop got stuck while booting:
[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SknKR.jpg)

Previously I faced the problem that my OS could not start because disk space was full. In order to solve disk space issue:

- I opened the grub menu -> advanced options,
- executed the clear command to remove unused packages,
- executed the root command to start root shell and removed some files to free disk space (disk is now around 20% free).

But when I boot my laptop in got stuck and I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: What files did you remove? Seems you removed something you should not have.

Comment: Some video files, which are not crutial.

Comment: Seems they might have been. What ever you did appears to have broke the system. I suggest a reinstall.

Comment: I guess clear command uninstalled packages that are needed OS to work properly and broke my machine. What the point of that grub command if breaks system :).

Comment: In fairness, we don’t know if what you deleted caused the problem - your system wasn’t booting up before you deleted the files - it may not just have been lack of disk space causing the original problem.